# Nested IFF query in MSAccess returning wrong number of arguments

Tags: microsoft-access, sql, query

I am trying to write a nested IFF query in MSAccess, but on running the error returned is "Wrong number of arguments"

My two fields Paper1 and Paper2 are of datatype True/False

The Query I wrote in DesignView is

```
Feedback: IIf([Paper1],"No comment","", Iff([Paper2],"No comment",""))
```

If Either Paper1 or Paper2 is True then I would like to return "No Comment" otherwise show nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct condition:

`Iif (paper1 or paper2,"no comment","")`